# Firebase implementation in flutter issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am having a lot of issues with implementing firebase in my flutter project, I had to revert back from 4.3 to 4.2 because of gradle errors. Now it is taking forever to load it on my emulator, I switched to an actual device but that install wont open. Has anyone implemented firebase messaging in a flutter project recently? I’m about to scrap the whole idea of using it.

Ive added the required lines to build.gradle and app/build.gradle and to my yaml file and thats it.

Comment: I had also some problems so I just used version 3.3.0 of gradle

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing firebase_core from my yaml file

Comment: Are you just receiving notifications or sending them from the app too? I am trying to send from the app as well.

Comment: If I would want to send it from the app, I would create a function on firebase that will handle it when the app request it via HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working as of today (2019-09-27 20:00 UTC, because flutter builds can break at any moment), and I'll let you know what I have in my build in order to get it to work (bit too long for a comment). I have tested that it works in both iOS and Android and builds correctly for release.

Firstly, switch to the flutter master channel `flutter channel master`. This is to fix a gradle appbundle naming issue.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
```

android/build.gradle (note the change in gradle version)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

android/gradle.properties (change for AndroidX)

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the same file make sure in the `defaultConfig` section you've changed the `testInstrumentationRunner` as follows:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Make sure you've added your `google-services.json` to android/app folder. I assume at some point this will all be nicely documented but at the moment it's a bit wild-west.