# How to receive custom data when app is terminated through push notification using firebase_messaging?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

As in title, what is the current workaround in order to receive custom data when the user click on a notification when the app is terminated?

Seems like on Android [is not possible](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#receiving-messages) to receive a data message in the onLaunch (which is the ideal way)
On IOS i hadn't tried yet since i'm facing this issue first.

Any clue?

Additional infos: The notification that i'm sending through a `firebase cloud function` are in this form:

```
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

on the `onResume` i'm able to perform an action, but the `onLaunch` seems to not be called.

Comment: You can try using Custom **JSON Payloads**.

Answer (score 2):

This is the format that your payload should take with data included. It does work as this is how I have gotten it to work in my project. Additionally to get everything to work correctly, there is an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58140867/1495728) that might be helpful for general project setup:

```
 {
      notification: {
        title: 'A title',
        body: 'The body.'
      },
      data: {
        // your data here
      },
      android: {
        ttl: 3600 * 1000,
        notification: {
          click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
        }
      },
      // The below is for iOS specific properties
      // apns: {
      //   payload: {
      //     aps: {
      //       badge: 42
      //     }
      //   }
      // },
      tokens: [] // or a single 'token'
    }
```

Comment: what is the `android` key is supposed to do?

Comment: there's specific properties that only relate to one platform. The android one is specific only for android notifications, and apns is for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you already getting data onLaunch, just need to wait a little bit. I wrote it because I came across the same thing.

Can you try this,

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async { .. },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async { .. },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Timer(const Duration(seconds: 7), () {
        // your process...
      });
    });
  },
);
```

Also in my situation, i used it like that, and solved.

```
onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((ignored) {
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        if (CurrentUser.currentUser != null) {
          timer.cancel(); // important **
          // redirect process with post details inside data
          if (message['data']['type'] == NotifTypes.NEW_POST)
            goGroupAndPost(Map.from(message['data'])); 
        }
      });
    });
  },
```

Comment: on firebase for flutter fcm documents says, with data message it is destroyed when the app is terminatef

Answer (score 0):

Telling if your Activity is in the foreground (and reacting differently) can be a little tricky. My favorite way is to register a local `BroadcastReceiver` in the Activity and then do a `sendBroadcast` from the service. You will get **true** from that method if your receiver is running (meaning your app is in the foreground, and **false** otherwise.

You can see an example of this (using GCM, but the logic is the same for FCM) [Source](https://github.com/googlearchive/easygoogle/blob/9391f7f595b52453567033b3129718e9b034267e/easygoogle/src/main/java/pub/devrel/easygoogle/gcm/EasyMessageService.java)

Also this is a great example [MyFirebaseMessagingService](https://gist.github.com/jirawatee/85d4b46a89b9ae821b63c31f5d5189de)